# How to get alerted when the dependency of a program is updated and the program needs to restart?

Tags: upgrade, updates, dependencies, restart

It just occurred to me that often when I upgrade software (through the usually repository `apt-get` means) I am upgrading software which another program has as one of its dependencies, and though I can check whether or not my system needs a restart from any of the updates, I cannot easily check if I need to restart any of my programs due to the fact that a dependency update my mean that it confuses the program(s) which is using it currently.

So now that you understand where I am coming from, my question is, how can I check after an update if any of the software which was updated is used by any other software on my machine and thus the software needs to be restarted? Can someone make a script which at least finds which applications may have been affected by this if not which program definitely need a restart?

**At the very minimum** I just want to be able to find out which other applications have listed a certain application as a dependency.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: If it's not a kernel update, no need for restart the machine.

Comment: @xangua: Well, sometimes the application does require it in other times (I am sure that I have come across them), but that does not really answer my question about other applications needing a restart as opposed to my entire system.

Comment: What applications? I've never encountered this problem.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181697/70524

Comment: @xangua: You think I remember? But it's definitely happened before. Anyway, at the very minimum I just want to be able to find out which other applications have listed a certain application as a dependency.

Comment: `apt-cache rdepends PACKAGENAME --installed` will return all installed packages which have PACKAGENAME as first level dependency. You can add the `--recurse` flag, but prepare for tons of output then.

Comment: @SuperSluether: Why on earth do you think that my question is a duplicate of that? If you bothered to read my question you would see that I am asking something completely different. I want to know if I need to restart applications, not the entire machine. And at the very minimum I want to know all the packages installed on my machine that have a certain package listed as dependency, how does that have anything to do with restarting the machine?

Comment: @ByteCommander: You say "first level dependency", do you mean the absolutely required ones? And the other levels being recommended etc?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda No, I mean direct dependency. If A depends on B and B depends on C, then B is a 1st level dependency of A whereas C is a 1st level dependency of B and a 2nd level dependency of A. (At least that's what I would call them, not sure about any official terminology...)

Comment: @ByteCommander: Oh yes, well I think that will do.